When do orbits of sets cover state space?
Suppose $(X, \mathcal{M}, \mu, T)$ is a measure-preserving dynamical system with $T$ invertible.
I am wondering what properties the dynamical system would need to have in order for the following to be true: for every positive measure subset $A \subset X$, there exists an $n$ such that
$$
A \cup T^{-1}(A) \cup \cdots \cup T^{-n}(A) \supset X,
$$
(or, since $T$ is taken to be invertible, $A \cup T^{}(A) \cup \cdots \cup T^{n}(A) \supset X$).
This property seems to hold for a variety of dynamical systems, such as rigid circle rotations.  So, my question is, what are the necessary and sufficient conditions for this to hold?  If not known, are there examples of "chaotic" (i.e. strongly mixing) dynamical systems for which this property does hold?  This seems to hold for polygonal billiards, and likely "chaotic" billiards (i.e. Bunimovich Stadium) for instance, but I cannot prove it.
What conditions must a dynamical system satisfy in order for the following weaker properties to hold?

For every positive measure subset $A$ of $X$, there exists an $n$ such that
$$
\mu[A \cup T^{-1}(A) \cup \cdots \cup T^{-n}(A)] = 1.
$$
For every positive measure subset $A$ of $X$, and every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists an $n$ such that
$$
\mu[A \cup T^{-1}(A) \cup \cdots \cup T^{-n}(A)] \geq 1-\epsilon.
$$


I don't think this is true, but what is true is that you can in finite time achieve arbitrarily large probability subsets and if you take the infinite union you get an almost sure subset of $X$

@FShrike Thanks that makes sense.  Although do you know if there is a property that we can add to a dynamical system to make it true?  For instance if we take a rigid irrational circle rotation this property holds
